# Count the sum of a left outer join table

Tags: sql

I have two tables which is

Student

| ID | Name | Gender | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Abby | Girl | street |
| 2 | Mark | Boy | street |
| 3 | Lula | Girl | street |
| 4 | Bren | boy | street |

Lessons

| ID | Lessons_code |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | MK2234 |
| 5 | 22324KL |
| 6 | KCS233 |

and I want to join these tables then get the sum result of the students that didn't took a lesson then group it by gender like this:

| Gender | total |
| --- | --- |
| Boy | 2 |
| girl | 1 |

I know it use `sum()` and `left outer join` (?) but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest `not exists`:

```
select s.gender, count(*)
from students s
where not exists (select 1
                  from lessons l
                  where l.id = s.id
                 )
group by s.gender;
```

You have a very awkward data model.  I would expect a column called `lessons.id` to refer to the *primary key* of the `lessons` table.  Instead. it seems to refer to a student.  A better name would be `student_id`.